# How can I locate text using a URL?

Tags: url, browser

How to locate text with URL? (like #~:)

In the post, I know a method that can locate text with URL, just like [http://xx.com#~:xxx](http://xx.com#%7E:xxx)

Then, I can enter the URL and get the contents with locating the text "xxx".

But I don't know the expect method now, and somebody here can help?

Thx.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.